# Use of em for headers

Tags: css, font-size

I'm new to the use of em. I've always used px so far but it's time to move on.
I'm stuck with my headers. I've got an H2 and an H6 with the same styling

```
font-size:1.2em;
line-height:1.2em;
```

When I put both headers in the same parent element they are displayed in a different size. How is that possible? Are they relative to the parent or are they relative to the default font-size of themselves.

http://jsfiddle.net/SBAHa/1

Comment: try making them important by putting `!important;`.. This will override the default values..

Comment: Please post some HTML as well

Comment: @Hiren http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: @HirenPandya Ugh, `!important`...

Comment: !important is a very horrible hack for CSS, please don't use that. Defeats the point of proper css coding completely.

Comment: Relative anything is relative to parent container. In general, default values do not apply at all when you set a value. I hope you get an answer with a proper reference link.

Comment: !important won't help

Here you can see what happens
http://www.joets.be/test/index.html
Halfway the page, left column, Sofie en Hans zijn ...

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem).

Comment: Are you able to provide us with a jsfiddle, or provide more code. As what you are trying to do is correct in theory, but there may be a mistake elsewhere leading to this error.

Comment: As @ASouthorn says, it sounds like you're doing the right thing. The only thing I can suggest is to check the dev tools in your browser of choice and check what CSS is actually being applied; it's possible that there's some other style overriding this one that you hadn't realised. I would need to see it in action to give a better answer, so perhaps you could give us a demo of the problem on jsFiddle or similar?

Comment: That is not possible. `em` quantities are relative to the element's own font size, *except* if used on its own font size in which case it's relative to its parent's font size.

Comment: I'm not sure how this got 7 up-votes! Can you provide an example please. What you are stating will not be true by default. Some of your code must be effecting it elsewhere - http://jsfiddle.net/ef6J8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link you sent (`joets.be/test/index.html`), the reason this is happening is because you have an anchor tag inside the heading elements.

The `<a>` inside the H2 has font sizing styles attached to it, whereas the one inside the H6 does not. If you apply your 1.2em styling to the `<a>` instead of the headings, then that will work.

So essentially, do this:

```
h2 a, h6 a{
    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height:1.2em;
}
```

Edit: I've looked at the CSS file itself, can you just remove the "h2 a" from line 339?

Answer (score 1):

The actual size of an element’s em is computed relative to the font-size of its parent element.

Have a look at this great article that helped me understood relative mesures: http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids

Comment: I get how it works but if I give the same styling to different elements and put them both in the same parent they have to be displayed the same way, not?

Comment: @user2287715 Please, put these comments (and the jsfiddle) as new edit in your question :)